# ¿Como resolver el método onBackPressed de dialogo de cierre de sesión que no más se ejecute cuando esta en activity principal?

Tags: java, android-studio

Tengo un activity principal como menú el cual llama diferentes `Fragment` por medio de `navigation component`, he implementado un método de `onBackPressed` que muestra un dialogo de cierre de sesión cuando se presiona el botón físico,en el activity principal funciona bien, pero cuando estoy en un `Fragment` y quiero regresar a activity principal por medio del botón físico me lanza la alerta de cierre de sesión, hay alguna manera de que solo se ejecute cuando se este en el activity principal.

**Método onBackPressed**

```
public void onBackPressed(){
    AlertDialog.Builder myBulid = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    myBulid.setMessage("¿Estas seguro de cerrar tu sesión?");
    myBulid.setTitle("Mensaje!");
    
    myBulid.setPositiveButton("Si", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            finish();
        }
    });
    myBulid.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog dialog = myBulid.create();
    dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Este Fragment se encuentra en la Activity principal o en otro Fragment?

Comment: @Elenasys se encuentra en la activity principal  fragment container

Answer (score 0):

Ten en cuenta que cuando navegas con navigation lo que haces es automatizar funciones de [supportFragmentManager](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/fragmentmanager?hl=es-419), así que puedes revisar en tu activity que Fragment está cargado en tu fragment_container cuando se dispare el OnBackPressed y si está cargado un fragmento principal dispare el dialog y en caso contrario llame a la funcion onBackPressed de application.

Ejemplo:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    when(supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container)){
        is OneFragment -> Toast.makeText(this, "This fragment cannot go back",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        is TwoFragment -> super.onBackPressed()
    }
}
```

Para mas información puedes ver [este hilo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294603/how-do-i-get-the-currently-displayed-fragment) de stackoverflow

EDIT: Te di la respuesta con Kotlin, en java puedes crear una instancia de Fragment F, asignarle el valor con findFragmentById igual, y hacer un if con instanceof